# Real analysis questions

Tags: calculus

Let S be a set of $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ where summation of $\sum_{i=1}^4 x_i^2=1$
and $m= $minimum of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ where summation of $|x_i|$ where $1\le i\le 4$
and $M=$ maximum of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ where summation of $|x_i|$ where $1\le i<=4$

There for $\frac mM$ equals:
Option a $0$

Option b $1/4$

Option c $1/2$

Option d $3/4$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I find the first paragraph to be totally garbled and impossible to make any sense of.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that $\dfrac{m}{M}$ could be $0$ but it does not have to be. For example, take $x_1 = 1$ and $x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = 0$. In  this case, $m = 0$.

I do not see why you should expect $\dfrac{m}{M}$ to have a unique value. I am also assuming that this is not a probability question.